# Can I run Tomcat securely on port 443 and insecurely on 8080

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat6

Let me explain my situation.

Currently, I have a lot of applications running on Tomcat 6, on the default port 8080.

I just created some applications that will need a log in.  I'm going to buy an SSL certificate to install on this server.

I don't like the idea of using port 8443 because it makes the URL more complicated.
If I run Tomcat on port 80, I'd have to change dozens of links and I'd have to run Tomcat as root ( rather than tomcat ).

Is there any problem running the insecure applications on port 8080 but having the secure run on port 443?

I'm imagining my setup will have URLs that look like this:

> http://mydomain.com:8080/report/controller?id=weather
>
> https://mydomain.com/secure/controller?id=profile

Is this possible?

Comment: Won't you have to run Tomcat as root for port 443?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly OK. Just configure the connectors to use the respective ports. But for 443 I'd guess root would be required as well.

Comment: One caveat though is if you're on *nix and run as non-root as only root can bind to ports < 1024 , but it should't be hard to find docs on how to work around that.

Comment: The usual thing is to bind to the port and then drop to a normal, minimal-privileged user. Don't know how Tomcat is set up to handle that (without the Apache httpd in front).

Comment: How can I change to opposite ? I mean we are using client certificate on browser to run the application. Have same redirect port to 8443. Now we want to run again on HTTP only rather that HTTPS.

Answer (score 39):

Setup HTTP connector on 8080 and HTTPS connector on 8443.  In your `<Connector>` declaration add `proxyPort` attribute and set it to default HTTP and HTTPS port ( 80 and 443 respectively ).  Setup firewall redirect rule from 80 to 8080 and from 443 to 8443.  Then the server will accept regular http and https URLs without the need to specify port numbers.

Below is a sample declaration of these connectors.

```
<Connector
  maxSpareThreads='75'
  port='8080'
  proxyPort='80'
  enableLookups='false'
  maxThreads='150'
  connectionTimeout='20000'
  disableUploadTimeout='true'
  minSpareThreads='5'
  maxHttpHeaderSize='8192'
  redirectPort='443'
  acceptCount='200'
/>

<Connector
  SSLEnabled='true'
  keystoreFile='/path/to/keystore.jks'
  maxSpareThreads='75'
  port='8443'
  proxyPort='443'
  algorithm='SunX509'
  enableLookups='false'
  secure='true'
  maxThreads='150'
  connectionTimeout='20000'
  disableUploadTimeout='true'
  scheme='https'
  minSpareThreads='5'
  maxHttpHeaderSize='8192'
  sslProtocol='SSL'
  acceptCount='200'
  clientAuth='false'
/>
```

And here are some redirect IPTABLES commands:

```
# Redirect external packets
-A PREROUTING -j NAT-Port-Redirect

# redirect http traffic
-A NAT-Port-Redirect -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
# redirect https traffic
-A NAT-Port-Redirect -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

Comment: Although the poster marked the reply above as an answer, your solution is much better.

Comment: Great and clean solution. I did this for redirecting on Ubuntu: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443.

Comment: I followed the above steps. But I got

Error code: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Comment: @arulraj.net.  You are probably required more advanced SSL configuration.  Read Tomcat documentation on SSL support.  If you are getting this error, it means that at least your client and server are connecting on port 443.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed :D

Comment: All it took was the one iptables command provided in the comment by hsnm.