# something wrong with my server.xml in tomcat for ssl on amazon ec2 single instance

Tags: tomcat, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have a single-instance of tomcat running on elastic beanstalk / ec2 - and I'm trying to configure SSL.  I've imported my cert (and the CA chain) into my keystore and I'm trying to get tomcat to respond on port 443.  I've opened up the port on the EC2 server, but tomcat doesn't seem to be responding to it.  Do you see anything wrong with my server.xml?

```
            <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
            <!--
              Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
              contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
              this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
              The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
              (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
              the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

                  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

              Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
              distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
              WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
              See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
              limitations under the License.
            -->
            <!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
                 define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
                 Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
             -->
            <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
              <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
              <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
              -->
              <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
              <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
              <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
              <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
              <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
              <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
              <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
              <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

              <!-- Global JNDI resources
                   Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
              -->
              <GlobalNamingResources>
                <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
                     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
                -->
                <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
                          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
                          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
                          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
                          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
              </GlobalNamingResources>

              <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
                   a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
                   so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
                   Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
               -->
              <Service name="Catalina">

                <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
                <!--
                <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
                    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
                -->


                <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
                     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
                     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
                     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
                     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
                     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
                -->
                <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                           connectionTimeout="20000"
                           redirectPort="8443" />

                    <!-- BEGIN SSL CONFIGURATION -->

                <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                           connectionTimeout="20000"
                           redirectPort="8443" />


                   <Connector port="443" SSLEnabled="true"
                   maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                   keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat7/.keystore"
                   keystorePass="MY_PASSWORD"
                   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />

                <!-- END SSL CONFIGURATION -->


            <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
                <!--
                <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
                           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                           connectionTimeout="20000"
                           redirectPort="8443" />
                -->
                <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
                     This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
                     connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
                     described in the APR documentation -->
                <!--
                <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
                           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
                -->

                <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
                <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


                <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
                     every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
                     analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
                     on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
                     Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

                <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
                <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
                -->
                <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

                  <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
                      /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
                      /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
                  <!--
                  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
                  -->

                  <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
                       via a brute-force attack -->
                  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
                         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
                         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
                         available for use by the Realm.  -->
                    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
                  </Realm>

                  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
                        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

                    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
                         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
                    <!--
                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
                    -->

                    <!-- Access log processes all example.
                         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
                         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" rotatable="false"
                           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto" internalProxies="10\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|192\.168\.\d+\.\d+|169\.254\.\d+\.\d+|127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|172\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\.\d+\.\d+" />
                  </Host>
                </Engine>
              </Service>
            </Server>
```

Comment: how do you know it is not responding ? have you open ports in security groups?

Comment: I can pull up the app on port 80 but not 443.  I've added HTTPS port 443 in the security group.  I just looked in the tomcat log and I see this.  I'm checking permissions now.

Comment: Jun 11, 2014 1:49:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-443"]
Jun 11, 2014 1:49:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-443"]
java.net.BindException: Permission denied <null>:443
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:407)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:623)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
 at

Comment: After adjusting permissions on my keystore, I'm still getting the error above (Failed to initialze endpoint).  When I generated the cert request and imported it into my keystore, I was using the default keystore file, which is /home/ec2-user/.keystore.  I found that that file path wasn't accessible by tomcat, so I copied the keystore file to /usr/share/.keystore.  However, the ownership of the file was still ec2-user.  I

Comment: I've changed that so that the file is owned by ec2-user:tomcat and temporarily set permissions to 777.  Do you have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  I haven't done SSL on linux before, so I'm very clumsy with this.  The part I added to the server.xml above is between the comments of BEGIN / END SSL CONFIGURATION.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late to help you but for anyone else searching:

Linux generally prevents non-root users from opening ports below 1024.
You can change the port to a higher one and forward it to 443.
Here is an example of how to forward your ports: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561888/1299497

Comment: I started Tomcat as root, and still got this error:    SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-443"]
java.net.BindException: Permission denied <null>:443